# Exception java in thread java.util.NoSuchElementExcpetion

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that must to verify if a sting is equal at one of error. If yes, he put a flag=1. My trouble is that the thread never enter in the if and he gives this exception: `java.util.NoSuchElementExcpetion: no line found`. This is the part of my code:

```
    String can = String.valueOf(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    String pad = String.valueOf(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());

    final String err = String.valueOf("WARNING: NO PAD nodes found on channel "+can+" . Exit!");
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final int[] flag = new int[1];
    flag[0]=0;

    try {
        if(pathFile!=null){
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("testpad -i -c"+can+" -n"+pad+" "+pathFile);
            final InputStream inStream = p.getInputStream();
            Thread uiThread = new Thread("UIHandler") {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
                  Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);

                  while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                     System.out.println(scan.nextLine());

                     if(err==scan.nextLine()){
                         flag[0] = 1;

                     }
                     latch.countDown();

                  }
               }
            };
            uiThread.start();
            latch.await();

            if(flag[0]!=1){
                this.dispose();
                new menu().setVisible(true);
            }
            else{
                Exception e = new Exception("Error!");
                Component f = null;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, err, e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
        else{
            Exception e = new Exception("Error!");
            Component f = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Choose a configuration file", e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(inizio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(inizio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I'm new of java and I have tried everything that I known.

Comment: Post full stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
System.out.println(scan.nextLine());

if(err==scan.nextLine()){
```

Your code reads two lines instead of one.

```
String s = scan.nextLine()
System.out.println(s);

if(err.equals(s){
```

Should work better.

Comment: That works well, it enters in the if construct but the latch.await don't work and the value of the flag is 0 before to be modified. How fix this trouble?

Comment: are you sure you shouldn't do the countDown inside the if?